# OpenShift redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS on Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)

Tags: tomcat, openshift

I would like to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS on Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0), I haven't found any working solution yet while wondering someone knows the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a KB put together on this topic on OpenShift: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/kb/kb-e1044-how-to-redirect-traffic-to-https

Hope it helps!